# What was the professor counting regarding constraint forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I am taking a mechanics class at university. Last week we started describing movement over a curve; we are given a natural parametrisation $s(t)$, and then we have the following relations:

$$ \vec{r}(t) = \vec{r}(s(t)) $$
$$ \vec{v} = \dot{\vec{r}} = \frac{d \vec{r}}{ds} \dot{s} = \vec{e}_t \dot{s} $$
$$ \vec{a} = \ddot{s} \vec{e}_t + \dot{s} \frac{d \vec{e}_t}{ds} \dot{s} = \ddot{s} \vec{e}_t + \kappa \dot{s}^2 \vec{e}_n $$

We said the coordinate system $\{ \vec{e}_t, \vec{e}_n, \vec{e}_b \}$ is called an intrinsic coordinate system (it consists of unit vector in tangential, normal and binormal direction). This far, everything's ok.

Then he wrote the Newton's equation:

$$ \vec{F}' = m \vec{a} = m (\ddot{s} \vec{e}_t + \kappa \dot{s}^2 \vec{e}_n ) $$

He stated that something "feels wrong" about this, since the number of equations and unknowns doesn't match. This is where I first got confused: what are those equations and unknowns that he mentions? If we write Newton's formula in vector form, taking the intrinsic basis, we get:
$$ (m \ddot{s}, \kappa \dot{s}^2, 0) = (F_x', F_y', F_z') $$

I see we get three equations, but I'm not sure what the unknowns are, and not even which quantities we are supposed to know; do we know $F$ or do we know $s, \dot{s}, \ddot{s}$? Again, what exactly are the unknowns? (I hope I'm right at least in counting the three equations)

Then he said that in fact $\vec{F}' = \vec{F} + \vec{S} $, where $\vec{F}$ is called *active force* and $\vec{S}$ is called, I believe, *constraint force* (in my language it's something like force of bonds; if my translation is wrong, let me know, I'll change the question). He further said that all forces which have a physical origin and act on particles are active forces, while constraint forces pull material points toward curves.

He than said that we are still in troubles. If we write:

$$ m (\ddot{s} \vec{e}_t + \kappa \dot{s}^2 \vec{e}_n ) = \vec{F} + \vec{S}$$
$$ m \ddot{s} = \vec{F} \vec{e}_t + \vec{S} \vec{e}_t $$
$$ m \kappa \dot{s}^2 = \vec{F} \vec{e}_n + \vec{S} \vec{e}_n $$
$$ 0 = \vec{F} \vec{e}_b + \vec{S} \vec{e}_b $$

Now, he said, there are too many unknowns. Once again, I have no idea what he is talking about here.

He added that we can fix this if we add a constitutive equation, namely:

$$ \vec{S} \cdot \vec{e}_t = 0 $$

He said that if this is true, then we are talking about smooth curves (in the sense of no friction).

So, all in all, my question can be summarized as follows:

What are the equations and unknowns that my professor is talking about and that we are counting? How many are there? What are the equations and unknowns in the second part, when we add $\vec{S}$? What exactly are the equations and unknowns when we add the constitutive equation?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/734625/2451

Comment: Hi Matthew. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic it says edit or ask a new question. I edited it, but then decided to close it and instead ask another question.

Comment: [This issue](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13577/2451) is currently under review.